# Socket IO emitting messages multiple times of agent

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new to Socket.io and I'm writing a program to connect with a chat agent.

Before posting this question I've referred the below questions, but, unfortunately didn't find a solution.

1. [socket.io emits multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265731/socket-io-emits-multiple-times)
2. [Socket.io returning multiple times for one event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56975534/socket-io-returning-multiple-times-for-one-event)
3. [socket.on event gets triggered multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788422/socket-on-event-gets-triggered-multiple-times)
4. [Socket.io message event firing multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162582/socket-io-message-event-firing-multiple-times)

Here is my client side code.

```
//Connect
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');

//Query Dom
var message = document.getElementById('message'),
    handle = document.getElementById('handle'),
    btn = document.getElementById('send'),
    output = document.getElementById('output'),
    feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');


//Emit Events
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (message.value === 'Transfer') {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(message.value));

        socket.emit('transfer', {
            message: message.value,
            handle: handle.value
        });
    }
    if (message.value !== 'Transfer') {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(message.value));

        socket.emit('U_chat', {
            message: message.value,
            handle: handle.value
        });
    }

});

//Listen for Events
socket.on('A_chat', data => {
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    feedback.innerHTML = '';
    output.innerHTML += `<p><strong>${data.handle}:</strong> ${data}</p>`
});
socket.on('U_chat', data => {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    feedback.innerHTML = '';
    output.innerHTML += `<p><strong>${data.handle}:</strong> ${data}</p>`
});
```

and here is my server side code.

```
var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(`Connection Established ${socket.id}`);
    socket.on('transfer', (data) => {
        console.log(`TeNSFER TO Agent`);
        main(socket);
    })
});


//LA Communication
async function main(socket) {
    console.log(`Entereed`)
    const getSessionId = await helperFunctions.sessionId();
    var tempVar;
    if (getSessionId.success === true) {
        sessionkey = getSessionId.data.key;
        affinity = getSessionId.data.affinityToken;
        sessionid = getSessionId.data.id;

        const body = {
            //body params
        };

        const sendingChatRequest = await helperFunctions.sendingChatRequest(
            body,
            affinity,
            sessionkey
        );

        if (sendingChatRequest === true) {
            pullmessageorg = await helperFunctions.pullingMessages(
                affinity,
                sessionkey
            );

            while (pullmessageorg.messages[0].type != "ChatEnded") {

                if (pullmessageorg.messages[0].type === "ChatRequestSuccess") {
                    io.sockets.emit('A_chat', ' Waiting for agent to accept your request.');
                }
                if (pullmessageorg.messages[0].type === "ChatEstablished") {
                    io.sockets.emit('A_chat', 'Agent Accepted');
                    io.sockets.emit('A_chat', ' Available');
                }

                if (pullmessageorg.messages[0].type === "ChatMessage") {
                    io.sockets.emit('A_chat', pullmessageorg.messages[0].message.text);
                    socket.on('U_chat', async (data) => {
                        io.sockets.emit('U_chat', data.message);
                        let text = data.message;
                        const sendMessage = await helperFunctions.sendMessages(
                            text,
                            affinity,
                            sessionkey
                        );
                    })
                }
                const pullingMessagesAgain = await helperFunctions.pullingMessages(
                    affinity,
                    sessionkey
                );
                pullmessageorg = pullingMessagesAgain;
            }
            return;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

When I run this program, the number of times client messages are getting printed are the total number of server messages.

For eg:
Server: Hi
Client: Hi
Server: what's up
Client: Nothing Much
Client: Nothing Much
Server: Anything Else?
Client: No
Client: No
Client: No

I'm unable to understand where I'm going wrong. Also I tried using `socket.once`, unfortunately, Unable to send multiple messages, like below.
Client: Hello (this is getting emitted)
Client: How are you? (this is not getting emitted)

Please let me know where Am I going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: try to move the main block inside socket.on.. socket.on('transfer', async (data) => { 
...main funciton code here })

Comment: Hi @Chanandrei, I don't think that will make any difference in OPs code